# dynamic modal not working properly in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm implementing a modal popup for a youtube in my Next app. I'm mapping through json object and passing them into cards. and when user selects specific card it displays a modal popup. and in that popup it is passed a url for a youtube vid.

my `index.js` code.

```
    const Contents = ({result , index}) => {
  let router = useRouter();
  const [modal, setModel] = useState(false);
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState([]);

  const getData = (vid)=>{
    let temp = [vid];
    setTemp(item =>[1, ...temp]);

    return setModel(true);
  }
    //console.log(result.items[1].snippet.title);
  return (
    <div className='grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-y-6 place-items-center lg:grid-cols-4 px-5 pt-5'>
        
        {result.items && result.items.map((res, idx)=>{
            //console.log(res.snippet);
            return (
                <div>
                  {/* <ContentCard result={res} index={index} key={idx}/> */}
                  <div>
                    <div onClick={()=>getData(res.snippet.resourceId?.videoId)}>
                      <div className='flex flex-col hover:scale-110 hover:transition-all hover:duration-200 hover:ease-in ease-out duration-200'>
                          <div className=' relative snap-center rounded-lg h-40 w-64  '>
                          <Image 
                              src={res.snippet.thumbnails.standard?.url || res.snippet.thumbnails.medium?.url || res.snippet.thumbnails.high?.url}
                              layout="fill"
                              objectFit="cover"
                              className={`h-full w-full bg-cover rounded-lg bg-no-repeat`} />
                          </div>
                          <Moment className=' text-dark-gray' date={res.snippet.publishedAt} format={"MMM Do YY"}/>
                          <div className=' text-sm font-thin font-serif text-med-gray'>{res.snippet.title.slice(0, 25).concat('...')}</div>
                      </div>        
                    </div>
                </div>
                {
                  modal === true ? <Modal vid={temp[1]} />: ''
                }
                </div>
            )
        })}
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

and my `modal.js`

```
return(
        <div className=" fixed inset-0 bg-bg-black bg-opacity-70 backdrop-blur-sm flex justify-center items-center">
            <div className="">
                <Video vid={vid} />
                {/* <h1>{vid}</h1> */}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

`Video.js`

```
const opts ={
        height: '70%',
        wresulthth: '70%',
        playerVars: {
           autoplay: 1, 
        }
    }
    return (
      <YouTube videoId={vid} opts={opts}/>
    );
```

my issue is when modal is fired up it displays the prop data, but when i use it for youtube videos it doesn't work. also uses a lot of my cpu and it lags when only modal is opened. what is the fix?

Comment: @juliomalves the vid is a prop that has the video URL and Youtube is not a component it's react package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube

Comment: @juliomalves yeah i meant videoId

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @juliomalves it just loads and doesn't display. no error msg

Comment: Where does the `modal` variable come from? Is that controlling _all_ the modals at the same time? Does it mean that when the value is `true` all the modals (and videos) get rendered at the same time? Can you please share the full code for the `index.js` page.

Comment: I will edit my code for index

Comment: Setting `modal` to `true` opens a modal for each content card you have in that page - which may explain why you're experiencing some lag when it opens. You should keep track of which modal you want to open instead of having a single boolean controlling all of them.

Comment: @juliomalves how can i do that, also when i pass the selected videoId it shows why not the vids